# SFTP post transfer processing is not happening properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, sftp

I am trying to use Spring Inbound Adapters to connect to SFTP. My requirement is I want to poll remote folder and once file is moved to local i want to move it to different local directory. Below is the code i am using:

```
@Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost(serverhost);
        sf.setPort(portname);
        sf.setUser(username);
        sf.setPassword(password);
        sf.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return  new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(sf);
    }

    @Bean
    public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(deleteRemoteFilesFlag);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(remotedir);
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
    public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
                sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File(basepath));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        source.setMaxFetchSize(fetchSize);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
    @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                Object payload = message.getPayload();
                if (payload instanceof File) {
                    File f = (File) payload;
                    boolean b = f.renameTo(new File(finalpath + f.getName()));
                    logger.info("File Saved to Final path is {} and status is {}", f.getName(), b);
                } else {
                    logger.info(message.getPayload().toString());
                }
            }

        };
    }
```

But what happens is if lets say there are 200 files in remote directory, code will transfer all 200 files to basepath then only it will start moving files from basepath to finalpath(what i want is after each transfer from sftp to basepath file should be moved to finalpath). Is there any way to achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why is the question since you use already `maxfetchSize` option of that message source which really is aimed for a goal you are pursuing.

See its docs for more details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-max-fetch

Comment: I have set maxfetchSize as 1 and as per my understanding it means in every poll it will fetch one file from remote which it is doing also. My problem is that handler method is not getting executed every time.

Comment: Doesn’t look like it is relevant for the original question some how. Probably you don’t have remote files to fetch on every poll